# Treatement of @ in searches

Tags: bug

I just tried to search for `\l@figure` and instead it searched for `\lfigure` (finding nothing of course).  Should this be fixed (soon)?

Comment: You can  search for the exact phrase by using `"\l@figure"`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5Cl%40figure%22

Comment: Since this is mostly a code-related search, you can use `code:"\l@figure"`, as suggested in the [search help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching).